# Why the if condition is always false?

Tags: java

I was doing some java coding exercises and this add 2 binary number exercise.
I am not sure why the if condition is always false, even if I put actual int into the variable.

whats the problem???

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        long bin1 = 10, bin2 = 101;
        int carry = 0, i = 0;

        int bin1Length = String.valueOf(bin1).length();
        int bin2Length = String.valueOf(bin2).length();
        int length;

        System.out.println("bin1: " + bin1Length);
        System.out.println("bin2: " + bin2Length);

        if(bin1Length > bin2Length){     // not sure why its always false in all 3 conditions
            length = bin1Length;
        } else if (bin2Length < bin1Length){
            length = bin2Length;
        } else if (bin1Length == bin2Length){
            length = bin1Length;
        }

        int [] finalOutput = new int [length];

        while(bin1 != 0 || bin2 != 0){
            finalOutput[i++] = (int)(carry + (bin1 % 10 + bin2 % 10) % 2);
            carry = (int)((carry + bin1 % 10 + bin2 % 10)/2);
            bin1 = bin1/10;
            bin2 = bin2/10;
        }

        if(carry != 0){
            finalOutput[i] = carry;
        }

        System.out.print("Output: ");

        while(i >= 0){
            System.out.print(finalOutput[i--]);
        }
    }
}
```

edit: and this is the error.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The values of `bin1` and `bin2` are hard-coded, hence `bin1Length` will **always** be less than `bin2Length` which causes your IDE to display the warning. Note that this is not a compiler error.

Comment: you can't use ```Math.max()```?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your first `if` condition and the following `else if` are the same.

have a better look on this:

```
    if(bin1Length > bin2Length){
        length = bin1Length;
    } else if (bin2Length < bin1Length){
        length = bin2Length;
    }
```

if `bin1Length` won't be greater than `bin2Length`, of course `bin2Length` is not smaller than `bin1Length`.

change it to this:

```
    if(bin1Length > bin2Length){
        length = bin1Length;
    } else if (bin1Length < bin2Length){
        length = bin2Length;
    } else if (bin1Length == bin2Length){
        length = bin1Length;
    }
```

Comment: oh you are right lol. but still the problem persist. the program doesn't go into the if block at all because it says the condition is always false. I am pretty sure what I am comparing are int not string.

Comment: this time it depends on initial `bin1` and `bin2` values. one of `if` or `else if` conditions will run definitely.

Comment: I even initial bin1Length and bin2Length with actual number but this still happens that's why I am so confused.

Comment: that's because you have hard coded their values, exchange their values and you will see the difference (this time `if` condition is true). have a look on this: https://www.onlinegdb.com/SkvlLplnU

Answer (score 0):

bin1Length is 2 and bin2Length is 3. That's why the if condition will always be false.

Also, optimized code would be:

```
length = bin1Length;
if (bin2Length > bin1Length)
    length = bin2Length;
```